# Related links - from other sites

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization, links, plugin-magic-fields

I'm in middle of re-building a website that's coded in a rather terrible custom CMS. Since the site is essentially a blog, I've been doing it in Wordpress.

One thing I'd like to do is be able to add a few "related links" to each post. These links are not the same thing as "related posts". When a new article is posted, I'd like the post author to be able to attach a handful of links from other sites (e.g. an article on nytimes.com, something from other blogs, etc). Each related link item would consist of the original URL, the Title, the Author(s), Source, and a brief description. See image for an example:
*Since I don't have enough rep points (yet), here's an image link instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlhbt.png*

My first thought was I could use Custom Fields - but this would quickly fall apart if there were multiple links. My current thought is to have each link as a separate Custom Post Type, but then I'm stumped on ways to link them to the post it should be shown with. If only WP had an auto-complete field that I could use for the article title. I'm using Magic Fields for certain categories, but it doesn't look like it would work here.

Is there anything I could use for this? I'm not very familiar with the WP core/plugins development, but I'm great with PHP/MySQL, so I don't mind having to code something up. I couldn't find anything by searching so I'm asking here. Any ideas for plugins/implementations that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin: http://eskapism.se/code-playground/simple-fields/

It's quite capable and should do what you want without getting your hands too dirty.

Comment: So I figured it out: even more Magic Fields. I didn't realize I could create a repeatable Field Group - which is EXACTLY what I needed. So I'm going with this.


However, your answer works perfectly fine as well - although it's a bit annoying to have to save the post before being able to add Simple Fields to it.